# Outlook keeps trying to load an addin that no longer exist/isnt available

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Time ago I installed an add-in for outlook from MS App Store, it was called "Kanban for Outlook"
it allow you to keep a kanban for your tasks in a way that I liked was practical to me.

Time has passed and after some upgrades to office and outlook I noticed I had a tooltip error in Outlook,stating that the addin is not available anymore, well I dont care about the add-in anymore, but I want to disable that tooltip/error message.
I went to outlook addins and it is not there, not under disabled addins either, searched the files inside outlook directory for *kanban* to see if I find it, but nothing comes up, searched the registry for "kanban", and no results.

[image: outlook error on add-in]

Where does Outlook store these addins information, is there some file or registry setting that I can get rid of? Or does it come from the Office MS Store? etiher way I want it gone, I read that some information about add-ins can be inside manifest files, but no idea if that was only for development purposes.
It is distracting and also since I can't use it I don't want it nagging about it.
If I search for it in the Office Store I get no information whatsoever.

I currently have Office 365 , at the time of installation of the addin I believe I had 2013 or 2010.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c2de00cb-3daa-443e-bdf2-e269d50a7107/how-to-permanently-remove-prevent-reinstallation-of-outlook-addins?forum=outlook

Just check the path in this thread and see if there is any information related to this specific add-in.

Comment: Nothing there either.